# Is a parsing between a parse of a script tag and his onload function possible?

Tags: javascript, parsing, onload

I wanted to know if this was possible that between a script tag being parsed and executed and his onload function called, an other script could be parsed and executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Include some script directly after the first script tag, and that should be executed immediately that it is loaded by the browser, but before the whole page is loaded (and thus any onload events run).

Comment: And what about the script added by javascript ? without adding the tags with html but with javascript

Comment: @Banou26 are you talking about loading another script via ajax?

Comment: Scripts added by adding a script tag with a src attribute via javascript

Comment: why not just add them the normal way directly into your HTML?

Comment: Modules loading for a webapp

Comment: that doesn't (directly) explain why you would load them via javascript. Are there certain conditions under which different ones are loaded? If you have some server-side processing going on, you can control which scripts are loaded using that. Then it would avoid the problem you're describing in the original question.